# Pandas read_excel openpyxl generates a ValueError

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Recently my code broke, like a week ago. Looks like something is going wrong with the `openpyxl` dependency. Hoping someone else has this issue and can tell me it's not just me being a bad programmer lol

#### Edit1:

The excel file I'm reading is generated as a `.xlsx` from Seeking Alpha's Portfolio Excel Export feature.

#### Edit2:

The Excel Export file now contains an added row with 2 empty conditionally formatted cells to a sheet that I don't even pass through to the `sheet_name` arg. The problem seems to be that `openpyxl` can't parse empty cells that have conditional formatting. How can I make `read_excel` only parse the sheets I listed? Or maybe drop the row that's causing problems?

After adding a "-" or removing conditional formatting, my script works. But I'd like to not have to do this every time I export the excel file. Also, the following warning appears now.

```
/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/bin/python3.9 /Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/analysis.py
/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py:308: 
UserWarning: Conditional Formatting extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
```

---

*My line of code that causes error*

```py
dic = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=sheet_names)
```

*Error message*

```
ValueError: Value must be one of {'equal', 'greaterThanOrEqual', 'containsText', 'beginsWith', 'notEqual', 'greaterThan', 'between', 'endsWith', 'notContains', 'lessThan', 'lessThanOrEqual', 'notBetween'}
```

*Complete Log*

```
/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/bin/python3.9 /Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/analysis.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/analysis.py", line 862, in <module>
    df = excel_data(path_excel, sheet_names)
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/analysis.py", line 129, in excel_data
    dic = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=sheet_names)
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 344, in read_excel
    data = io.parse(
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1170, in parse
    return self._reader.parse(
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 492, in parse
    data = self.get_sheet_data(sheet, convert_float)
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 548, in get_sheet_data
    for row_number, row in enumerate(sheet.rows):
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_read_only.py", line 79, in _cells_by_row
    for idx, row in parser.parse():
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py", line 145, in parse
    dispatcher[tag_name](element)
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py", line 288, in parse_formatting
    cf = ConditionalFormatting.from_tree(element)
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/formatting/rule.py", line 201, in __init__
    self.operator = operator
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 143, in __set__
    super(NoneSet, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "/Users/marcoucolon/Documents/GitHub/opt-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 128, in __set__
    raise ValueError(self.__doc__)
ValueError: Value must be one of {'equal', 'greaterThanOrEqual', 'containsText', 'beginsWith', 'notEqual', 'greaterThan', 'between', 'endsWith', 'notContains', 'lessThan', 'lessThanOrEqual', 'notBetween'}
```

Comment: did you give a try to different engines? sometimes it's an easy way to put the right engine when reading excel. reference pandas.read_excel() (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: This issue could be related to the fact that some cells in your Excel file use conditional formatting: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.formatting.rule.html#openpyxl.formatting.rule.Rule

Comment: @Laurent You're right, thanks for the comment. This was never an issue before, but the excel's creator added a row with 2 empty conditionally formatted cells to a sheet that I don't even pass through to the `sheet_name` arg. The problem is that `openpyxl` can't parse empty cells that have conditional formatting. How can I make `read_excel` only parse the sheets I listed? Or maybe drop the row that's causing problems?

Comment: Assuming that you are dealing with recent (.xlsx) Excel files, you could try and see what happens with an alternate engine to openpyxl, such as https://pypi.org/project/pylightxl/ and https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with Seeking Alpha (SA) xlsx. pandas 1.1.5 does read ok but current pandas 1.3.2 has this problem.
A possible hack workaround is to install older pandas in a different location and import that pandas version 1.1.5 as pd1 just to import the xlsx .
So pd is pandas 1.3.2
and pd1 is pandas 1.1.5
The following has some hints [Supporting multiple Python module versions (with the same version of Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001016/supporting-multiple-python-module-versions-with-the-same-version-of-python)

And use the target option in pip import as explained in  [Supporting multiple Python module versions (with the same version of Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001016/supporting-multiple-python-module-versions-with-the-same-version-of-python)

**Edited to add sample code**
Pandas is a large subsystem and multiple versions are a bit demanding to install. A simpler solution was to create a different environment ( I used conda) and execute a command ( .bat in windows .sh in unix)

sample SA_oldpandas.bat

```
echo old pandas 1.1.5
conda activate env-oldpandas 

cd {code directory}
echo ---GOING----
python SA_OldPandas.py
echo ---FINISHED---- %date% %time%
start excel SA_check.xlsx
```

basically the old Pandas code writes the data to a excel and the new code uses this

```
os.getcwd()
os.system('SA_oldpandas.bat')
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's great that you found this workaround.