# API versioning with blueprints causes colission

Tags: python, flask, versioning

The time has come where I need to release a new version for my api and still support the previous one.

I followed the instructions given in the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795561/support-multiple-api-versions-in-flask). Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to ask in the comments of that answer.

I have an app structure that looks like this:

```
+-- app/
    +-- api_2_0/
        +-- __init__.py
        (...)
    +-- api_2_1/
        +-- __init__.py
        (...)
   +-- __init__.py
```

Both are blueprints which I initialize this way in my `__init__.py` in the `create_app` method (I'm using the [app factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/) method):

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    (...)

    from .api_2_0 import api as api_2_0_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(api_2_0_blueprint, url_prefix='/api/v2.0')

    from .api_2_1 import api as api_2_1_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(api_2_1_blueprint, url_prefix='/api/v2.1')
```

But this causes:

```
AssertionError: A blueprint's name collision occurred between <flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x7f8e48e82c10> and <flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x7f8e48ef7150>.  Both share the same name "api".  Blueprints that are created on the fly need unique names.
```

It's true that both are called `api` inside their folders but I'm importing them with different names. Having to rename all the calls to `api` to something else for each version would make versioning painful and overall a code mess.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what is the purpose of __init__.py files in the api version folders?

Comment: @variable an `__init__.py` file tells python that the folder they are contained in is a package. See the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so it turns out I only had to change the Blueprint definition.

Before I had both blueprints defined as `api = Blueprint('api', __name__)` which caused the collision and made me think that I needed to change name of the variable `api`.

Turns out what I really needed to change is just the string `'api'` used in the call to `Blueprint`, so now my blueprints are defined as `api = Blueprint('api_2_0', __name__)` and `api = Blueprint('api_2_1', __name__)`, allowing me to keep the variable `api` the same in both cases and saving me the issue of chaging it everywhere.

I now realize this was a pretty silly question but I'm leaving this here in case someone runs with the same issue.

Comment: To save messing with that specific string each time you could use `__name__` for both arguments, I believe.