# Automatically duplicate and redirect version urls with Flask and Blueprint

Tags: python, flask

As [Support multiple API versions in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795561/support-multiple-api-versions-in-flask/28797512#28797512) (thanks Miguel) I structured my large API app with multiple folders for multiple versions.

My scenario: I have two versions, one (using Blueprint) routes to v1/, the other one routes to v2/. Version 2 has same methods as V1 but 10% of them have a different behavior (other methods are exactly the same).
What I'd like to do is creating all methods for V1 (assigning v1/ as url prefix with Blueprint), then creating only those 10% changed methods for V2 (assigning v2/ as prefix) and automatically duplicate and/or redirect other methods (no changing from versions) from v2 to v1.

The idea is to avoid multiple initialization of identical methods.

How can i do?
Thanks